# which will be more efficient in case of resource usage in php

Tags: php

I have a shared hosting. So I have to think a lot for resource usages as any extra resource usage makes chance higher for site suspension due to over resource usage.

In a php class, properties can get either from declaration or as an argument in function like this:

```
class sum{
public $a;
public $b;

public function sum(){
echo $a.' and '.$b;
}
}

$sum = new sum();
$sum->$a = 'Large Variable';
$sum->b = 'Short Variable;
```

or the same can be achieved by the following:

```
class sum{
public function sum($a=NULLL,$b=NULL){
echo $a.' and '.$b;
}
}
$sum = new sum();
$a = 'Large Variable';
$b = 'Short variable';
$sum->sum($a,$b);
```

In above, let $a is a large variable such as a javascript or page head section.

I assume, if I set a variable, then server allocate a memory location, size etc in the system. Suppose I set 10 variables in procedural php, system allocates 10 location for those 10 varaibles. Everytime I access a single variable, server use read operation for 10 different location of the system. Thus it increases read/write operation/resource usages.

On the other hand in object model, server allocates memory for whole object and properties inside the object has no extra allocation of space or location. Thus if I access properties of the object, system just read from one location (object's location). So it might have less resource usage. But it is completely my assumption, I am not sure whether memory and location access works like that.

So, If $a is set in above outside of object or inside of object, which of the above will use more cpu usage, memory, entry process of a server?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In your first case, you'd need to use `echo $this->a.' and '.$this->b;`, but you really are focusing on micro-optimisations, and almost certainly have more serious resource issues than this

Comment: Some people always thinks negatively. That was just an example, it is not a real code. My object is not to show you code in right way, there may be typing mistake as this is not real code and it is not the issue. I told at first why I am worried about resource usage and I don't know whether it is micro-optimization or have a big effect on resource usages. If I want to know, then what is your problem in it?

Comment: The problem is that many people consider that such "micro-optimisations" that might save a byte or two of memory, or a nanosecond or two of execution time is critical to the performance of their application, when elsewhere they're needlessly loading large volumes of data into memory, or have highly inefficient database queries, or excessively complex loops, other such inefficiencies that do have a major impact, but which they're not bothering to look at.... in this case, unless you're instantiating millions of instances of your sum class, you'll find the difference impossible.

Comment: If you do measure it, you'll also find that while the first example probably uses more memory (all of about 96 bytes per instance, plus the length of the strings), it's also probably faster because you don't have the overhead of pushing values onto the argument stack when calling the sum method, which you do with the second example.... so which resource is more important to you, processor cycles or memory?

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is better because the scope of the variable ends with the scope of the function. In the first approach the public variables will be there with the object until and unless the object gets removed from the memory..

I will still say it depends on the requirements of the system though.